# How to add an item to the top of a ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox

In my application I am adding items to a `ListBox` in C#. I am adding the collection of items which are held in a `StackPanel` using the code:

```
ListBoxControl.Items.Add(stackPanel);
```

But this adds the `StackPanel` to the bottom of the `ListBox`, is there any way of adding the `StackPanel` to the top rather than the bottom?

(It is not possible to add the items to the `ListBox` in reverse order.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [ItemCollection.Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.insert.aspx)

For example

```
myListbox.Items.Insert(0, myItem);
```

Comment: Fortunately the answer is right :) But I think you didn't read carefully the tags since your link points the `System.Windows.Forms.Listbox` instead of the `System.Windows.Controls.ListBox`.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the Insert method as Matthew mentioned before or just using Reverse().

```
ListBoxControl.Items.Add(stackPanel);
ListBoxControl.Items.Reverse();
```